# Getting 'e.entries is not a function' error in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, babeljs, shim

I've got an issue in Safari where I'm getting

> e.entries is not a function.

You can test yourself by loading [my site](https://surveyrewards.co.uk) in a safari browser. Just fill in some dummy details and press "Join".

I don't have a Mac to test on so I've been using a service by CrossBrowserTesting but I still can't seem to figure out where my problem is coming from, but it's happening within this block of code. This code gets transpiled with babel, it's a small npm module I created for this task.

```
/**
 * Convert FormData elements to JSON
 * @param {FormData} formData An object that is an instance of FormData 
 */
module.exports = formData => {
  if (!(formData instanceof FormData)) {
    throw new Error('Expected formData paramater to be an instance of FormData')
  }

  let o = {}
  for (let p of formData.entries()) {
    o[p[0]] = p[1]
  }

  return o
}
```

I have shimmed using [airbnb-shims](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airbnb-js-shims), but I still get the error.

Any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: There's no `entries` call in there?

Comment: It gets transpired using babel.

Comment: I don't see any errors. Safari 11.1.2

Comment: Does the form submit? I've had a friend test it on iphone moments ago and its not submitting. On my older iMac it throws the error too.

Comment: Well, babel doesn't transpile this specific code into one that has `entries` either. It must be somewhere else.

Comment: I had trouble with your date input. It forced me to use the format yyyy-mm-dd otherwise it told me I'm too young. After changing the date the form submitted fine.

Comment: @Turnip thats another issue I'm working on, the placeholder is not being set on safari. I've updated the question. I found where `entries` is being used. In a node module I created. Hmmm.

Comment: @BugHunterUK maybe the browser you are using doesn't support [`FormData.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries)

Comment: @MinusFour Safari doesn't support form data, but I have attempted to polyfill with https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill

Comment: @BugHunterUK the polyfill might not be working for you then. If your safari browser supports [`FormData.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/keys), it won't replace the `FormData` global object.

Comment: I'm going to rip this date input type out. Too much hassle with older browsers. I'll do it another way. I got the form data polyfill to work, but now its the `date` input type is problematic. Polyfill for that doesn't appear to be working. Feels so messy having to polyfill.